# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../user_module/User.js' does not provide an export named 'User' main.js:1

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I am having some difficulty getting a simple JavaScript module example to work. For the example code below I get an error stating:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../user_module/User.js' does not provide an export named 'User' main.js:1**

Here is my project directory structure:

module_tester
├──css
├   ├──module_tester_style.css
├──test
├   ├──main.js
├──user_module
├   ├──User.js
├──index.html

**Here is my index.html file:**

<!doctype html>

```
<head>
    <title>JS Modules</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/module_tester_style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./test/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Module Tester</h1>

    <h3 id="user_results">Enter User Data Below</h3>

    <form>
        <label for="userName" class="user-name">User Name:</label>
        <input id="userNameTF" type="text">

        <label for="dobMonth" class="dob-month">DOB Month:</label>
        <input id="userDobMonthTF" type="text">

        <label for="dobDay" class="dob-day">DOB Day:</label>
        <input id="userDobDayTF" type="text">

        <label for="dobYear" class="dob-year">DOB Year:</label>
        <input id="userDobYearTF" type="text">

        <button onclick="getAndDisplayUserAge()">Calculate Age</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Here is main.js:**

```
import { User, DateOfBirth } from '../user_module/User.js'

export function getAndDisplayUserAge() {
    let name = document.getElementById("userNameTF").value;
    let dobMonth = document.getElementById("userDobMonthTF").value;
    let dobDay = document.getElementById("userDobDayTF").value;
    let dobYear = document.getElementById("userDobYearTF").value;

    let user = new User(name, dobMonth, dobDay, dobYear);
    document.getElementById("user-results").value = user.toString();
    let dob = user.dob;
    console.log("User dob: " + dob);
}
```

**And here is User.js**

```
export default class User {
    constructor(initName, initMonth, initDay, initYear) {
        this.name = initName;
        this.dob = new DateOfBirth(initMonth, initDay, initYear);
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name + ", born "
                + this.dob.toString()
                + " (" + this.dob.calculateAge()
                + " years old" + ")";
    }
}

export class DateOfBirth {
    constructor(initMonth, initDay, initYear) {
        this.month = initMonth;
        this.day = initDay;
        this.year = initYear;
    }

    calculateAgeInYears() {
        // GET THE DATE RIGHT NOW
        let now = new Date();
        let ageInYears = now.getFullYear() - this.year;
        if (now.getMonth() - this.month)
            ageInYears--;
        else if (((now.getMonth() - this.month) === 0)
                && (now.getDate() < this.day))
            ageInYears--;
        return ageInYears;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting User class as default export so your import statement in main.js should look like this:

```
import User, { DateOfBirth } from '../user_module/User.js'
```

Comment: The good news is that solved my error. The new problem is now I have a different error. When I load the page and then click on my button it gives me a ReferenceError telling me it cannot find the getAndDisplayUserAge function.

Comment: Note that if I remove the "module" declaration from the declaration of the script in my index.html file and then comment out all usage of User inside my main.js it finds that function and executes it. But for some reason it doesn't find my callback function when I use it as a module. My assumption is that it's failing in its declaration because of some syntax error, but even if I comment out the method and only leave in a single console.log it doesn't find it as long as it's using modules.

Answer (score 0):

`export default Class User` means that `User` is a default export, which should be imported without brackets.
so your import statement should be >> `import User, { DateOfBirth } from '../user_module/User.js'`

Comment: The good news is that solved my error. The new problem is now I have a different error. When I load the page and then click on my button it gives me a ReferenceError telling me it cannot find the getAndDisplayUserAge function.

Comment: Note that if I remove the "module" declaration from the declaration of the script in my index.html file and then comment out all usage of User inside my main.js it finds that function and executes it. But for some reason it doesn't find my callback function when I use it as a module. My assumption is that it's failing in its declaration because of some syntax error, but even if I comment out the method and only leave in a single console.log it doesn't find it as long as it's using modules.

Comment: hey  @the_mg , so I've been trying to solve this, but I ran into this on javascript.info 
```Modules work only via HTTP(s), not in local files
If you try to open a web-page locally, via file:// protocol, you’ll find that import/export directives don’t work. Use a local web-server, such as static-server or use the “live server” capability of your editor, such as VS Code Live Server Extension to test modules.```
find the full reference here >> https://javascript.info/modules-intro